# Как отсортировать список строк на украинском

Tags: dart

Есть список улиц

```html
streets = [
    'Михайла Фрунзе',
    'Алма-Атинська',
    'Ватутіна',
    'Новоросійська',
    'Єсеніна',
    'Івасюка',
    'бульвар Героїв Сталінграду',]
```

Делаю так

```html
streets.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
```

На выходе получаю

```html
Івасюка
Єсеніна
і далі по алфафіту
Алма-Атинська
Ватутіна
```

Как сделать сортировку по украинскому алфавиту, то есть чтобы І и Є были на своих местах, а не в начале.

Comment: В `java` используется для этого `Local`. Поищите, что-то такое должно быть и в `dart`.

Comment: Странно, но на русском все нормально сортируется, только что проверил.